# How to show all data in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I don't want to get data from retrofit index [0]. I would like to show all data from retrofit. I use this tutorial **http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/12/Android-RecyclerView-Item-Click-Listener-Ripple-Effect.html**
MyPendingActivity.java

```
@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyPendingActivity.this, MyPendingCargoActivity.class);
   // intent.putExtra("ItemPosition", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

MyPendingCargoActivity.java

```
user = StoreUtil.getInstance().selectFrom("users");
        NetworkEngine.getInstance().getNotSending(user.getId(), new Callback<List<MyPending>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<MyPending> myPendings, Response response) {
              //  Intent intent = getIntent();
              //  int position = intent.getIntExtra("ItemPosition", -1);
                txt_taker_name.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_name) + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getShippingInformation().getName());
                txt_taker_address.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_address) + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getShippingInformation().getAddress());
                txt_taker_phone.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_phone) + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(0).getShippingInformation().getPhone());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: for loop? `myPendings`

Comment: I don't know. But i think it need to loop. I use for loop. It doesn't work. for(int i=0; i<myPendings.size(); i++){
             txt_taker_name.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_name) + ":" + " " + myPendings.get(i).getShippingInformation().getName());
                
         }

Comment: `setText()` will overwrite current value you will end showing last iteration data only, you need to concatenate all items then set them once in the textView

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your point, this is will help you.

```
user = StoreUtil.getInstance().selectFrom("users");
NetworkEngine.getInstance().getNotSending(user.getId(), new Callback<List<MyPending>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(List<MyPending> myPendings, Response response) {

        String name = getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_name) + ": ";
        String address = getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_address) + ": ";
        String phone = getResources().getString(R.string.str_taker_phone) + ": ";

        for(MyPending pending : myPendings) {
            name += pending.getShippingInformation().getName() + ", ";
            address += pending.getShippingInformation().getAddress() + ", ";
            phone += pending.getShippingInformation().getPhone() + ", ";
        }

        txt_taker_name.setText(name);
        txt_taker_address.setText(address);
        txt_taker_phone.setText(phone);
    }
});
```